# Is my Florith Homebrew Race Balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, races, homebrew-review

Second time asking about a homebrew race, so hopefully it is a bit more balanced than my previous one originally was.

> ## Florith
>
> Florith are nocturnal plant people who dwell in swamps, hunting prey, fighting with lizardfolk and using their mysterious powers to survive.
>
> **Ability Score Increase:** Your Dexterity score increases by 2, and either your Wisdom or Charisma score increases by 1.
>
> **Age:** Florith mature young, at 10, yet can live to around 500 years of age.
>
> **Alignment:** Florith are chaotic more often than not, preferring freedom to order. They generally don't have a natural preference towards good or evil, yet some florith may tend towards extremes.
>
> **Size:** Florith are generally as tall as humans, and are roughly half the weight of humans. Your size is Medium.
>
> **Speed:** You have a base walking speed of 30 feet, and a swimming speed of 30 feet.
>
> **Darkvision:** Nocturnal by nature, florith can see in the dark with ease. You can see in dim light within 60 feet of you as if it were bright light, and in darkness as if it were dim light. You can’t discern color in darkness, only shades of gray.
>
> **Florith Magic:** You know the [*primal savagery*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/primal-savagery) cantrip, and can cast it at will. At 3rd level, you can cast [*entangle*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/entangle) once with this trait, and can do so again after a long rest. At 5th level, you can cast the [*command*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/command) spell as a 2nd-level spell once with this trait, and can do so again after a long rest. Dexterity is your spellcasting modifier for these spells.
>
> **Razor Fangs:** Your fangs are natural weapons. If you use them to attack, you deal 1d6 piercing damage.
>
> **Florith Cunning:** You gain proficiency in the Survival skill.
>
> **Photosynthesis:** As long as you have access to direct sunlight, you don’t need to eat. You can still eat if you wish to.
>
> **Petal Boost:** You can add 1d6 to any ability check, attack roll, or saving throw once with this trait, and you regain the ability to do so after a long rest where you are exposed to direct sunlight.
>
> **Languages:** You can speak, read and write Common and Primordial.

Comment: I like the idea, but why are Florith nocturnal plant people who depend on sunlight for two of their traits to activate. ...it is D&D so why not make it the moon instead. It seems at odds with the lore you are creating.

Answer (score 9):

## This race is somewhat overpowered

While the race possesses no *individual* ability outside of what's concievably acceptable for races, the race consistently possesses the most powerful allowed version of abilities, as well as way too many abilities, and thus is overpowered.

The most out-of-line *individual* abilities are the spellcasting-- which is of the format of Drow or Tiefling spellcasting yet chooses spells of the power-level of e.g. Yuan-ti spellcasting and also gives the physical ability modifier members of the race want to specialize in, which is also the best ability modifier in general, as the spellcasting modifier-- and the petal boost, which adds a d6 instead of a d4 like every other ability that does that outside of bardic inspiration.

The real problem, though, as mentioned, is the overwhelming number of slightly-overpowered abilities:

Ability Increase: You have +2, +1, which is the best stat increase, except the +1 is also flexible, so it's even better. This is okay as a coping mechanism for an underpowered race.

Age: You live super long, but you also mature early, which is even better.  This isn't a big deal.

Speed: You get an alternative movement format, but you don't lose any base speed.  This is okay as a race's main ability.

Darkvision: This is okay on races that are otherwise pretty standard, and usually mostly a 'humans sell this off so they get to be overpowered' thing.

Florith Magic: You get the most allowable spells (three) and also the highest allowable casting level for one of them (second level) and also the spells have no overlap, restrictions, and are all useful almost all the time. Dex, the best ability score, is the casting ability.  This is appropriate as a race's main ability if it were also penalized e.g. by lacking darkvision, being small, having a vulnerability, being slow, getting less attribute points than normal, etc.

Razor Fangs: These are fine as a side ability for a standard race.

Florinth Cunning: This is fine as a side ability for a standard race.

Photosynthesis: This is fine as a side ability for a standard race.

Petal Boost: This is fine as the main ability for a race if it were also penalized in some way, probably by having less side abilities than normal.

Languages: This is fine.

So, in sum, your race has two main abilities, each of which should require the race to be otherwise below-standard to be okay, a pretty-normal main ability, three side abilities plus darkvision, and some extra minor stuff that you would expect if you were trying to make up for something being underpowered.  It should have, like, one main ability and two side abilities plus darkvision and then just minor stuff, or like four side abilities plus darkvision and then minor stuff and no main abilities.  So it's quite definitely overpowered compared to the standard races.

Comment: I have a separate page on another website for recording my races, so I've made some changes on that page for the Florith. Petal Boost is now only a D4, Photosynthesis has been cut, Command is now weakened to a LVL 1 Spell, and the Florith Magic now requires the Long Rest to involve being exposed to Direct Sunlight, as the Petal Boost already has. Is this better or do I need to make the +1 Static?

Comment: Also, what would the Musicus score for my Race be?

Comment: More changes: Florith Magic no longer requires the exposed to Direct Sunlight, but Petal Boost can only be used in direct sunlight now. Also, now the +1 is static, and for charisma. Charisma is now the Spellcasting modifier for Florith Magic,

Comment: One more Change: No more Primal Savagery.

Comment: RPG.SE is not a suitable forum for iterative design; see [this thread in meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/can-we-develop-a-system-to-avoid-discourage-subsequent-hombrew-critique-question). You might be better off asking for such feedback in [chat].